# How to open new tab only 1 time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, limit

```
<script>
$(document).click(function() { 
    window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
});
</script>
```

With above code, when I click anywhere, the tab will be opened. However, when I click more, the new tab will be opened. So, how to disable above code after click 1 time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery `.one()` http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
<script>
$(document).one("click",function() { window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");});
</script>
```

Comment: Or, depending on what is wanted, name the window something other than `_blank`.