# How to open only 1 new tab when linking several times to the same google document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am currently linking (some irrelevant stuff in) 2 gDrive Documents. For linking, I use bookmarks. They will be generated automatically and later on inserted as follows:

```
setLink = {};
links = ["somegeneratedstuff1", "somegeneratedstuff2", "andsoon"];
```

...Later on, for every entry (j) in links, I do the following:

```
setLink[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINK_URL] = "myurl/edit#bookmark=" + link[j];       
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getParagraphs()[1].editAsText().setAttributes(someNumber, someOtherNumber, setLink);
```

Now, there is a list of links. Their only difference is the part after the "#bookmark=", where the links lead to different parts of the document.
Whenever I click on one of the links, I get to exactly the point in the document I want to go.

**However**, I have not found a solution to link to the same tab over and over again. Every time I click on a link, it opens the same document in a new tab.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this? (preferably using JavaScript/Google AppsScript)

I found something similar, but I did not manage to apply this in my script:
[How to open new tab only 1 time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649594/how-to-open-new-tab-only-1-time)

Thank you for any input in advance!
(Also thank you, if you point out anything about my question I should ameliorate!)